Is there a term for this?: When you act like someone doing something offensive isn't offensive because you personally don't find it offensive?
I was on one of many of Reddit's "circlejerk" subreddits (pretty much troll pages) and I came across an interesting question:

What's the opposite of virtue signaling? You know,when you act like someone doing something offensive isn't offensive because you personally don't find it offensive?

And seeing that, I was wondering if there's a specific term for this.

There's vice signaling, but that, at least in the NYT usage is more about celebrating the vice because it's bad, than claiming an offensive action is not offensive.

Can you give an example of this? It doesn't seem familiar to me, and there may not be a term for something uncommon.

Some people may not be bothered by cursing or public nudity, but I don't think I've ever heard a term for this.

Sounds more like rationalizing the behavior to give it a pass.

Someone who is unaffected by material that most people might find to be offensive could be called

insensitive
not feeling or showing sympathy for other people's feelings, or refusing to give importance to something
It was a bit insensitive of Fiona to talk about fat people when she knows Mandy is desperate to lose weight.

Or they could be called

thick-skinned
Someone who is thick-skinned does not appear to be easily hurt by criticism
You do need to be thick-skinned to survive as a politician here.

Another suggestion is

impervious
If someone is impervious to something,they are not influenced or affected by something

